# "These credentials do not match our records." Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

i try to create function for change password member via Dashboard Admin, and when i am trying to do a login then get this error, and i am sure i enter correct values

this is my function for update member password

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
  $rules = array(
      'username'        => 'required|unique:members,username,'.$id,
      'email'           => 'required|unique:members,email,'.$id,
      'password'        => 'min:8',
      'retype_password' => 'min:8|same:password'
  );
  $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

  // process the login
  if ($validator->fails()) {
      return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
  } else {

      // Input
      $username       = Input::get('username');
      $email          = Input::get('email');
      $now            = new DateTime();

      // get old password
      $members = members::where('id',$id)->first();

      if (!empty('password') && !empty('retype_password')) {
        $password = $members->password;
      }else{
        $password = bcrypt(Input::get('password'));
      }


      // store
      $store = members::find($id);
      $store->status       = 1;
      $store->username     = $username;
      $store->email        = $email;
      $store->password     = $password;
      $store->updated_at   = new DateTime();
      $store->save();
      // redirect
      return redirect('system/members')->with('success','Data successfully updated');
  }
}
```

and this is Model members

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Notifications\MemberResetPasswordNotification;

class members extends User
{
    protected $table = "members";

    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];
    /**
     * Send the password reset notification.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return void
     */
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new MemberResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
}
```

this is my login function :

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

any solutions for me?

Comment: while updating, `unique:members,email,'.$id,` remove this and `unique:members,username,'.$id,` this too.

Comment: done, but it still not working

Comment: could you please show us your member model and when you are having the problem, saving the old one or new one?

Comment: you should use `Hash::make` not `bcrypt()` for passwords

Comment: Class name must be first letter capital and you have to save it as the same, have you checked by debugging exactly where the issue arise?

Comment: @Rits because my class not using capital on first later

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi Thank you so much. it works.

Answer (score 1):

**Change the logic (if/else) and there is no field like `empty('password')` and `empty('retype_password')`**

```
if (!empty(Input::get('password')) && !empty(Input::get('retype_password'))) {
    # new password
    $password = Hash::make(Input::get('password')); 
}else{
    # old Password
    $password = $members->password;
}
```

Make sure this `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;` on top

---

And password re-check Laravel has the easiest way to do it.

**In Form**

```
<input type="password" name="password" >
<input type="password" name="password_confirmation" > # this should be password_confirmation retype_password filed in yours
```

**In controller**

Just add this rule

```
'password'         => 'required|min:8|confirmed', # just add confirmed thats it
```

---

**Edit**

Use this to login

```
$username = Input::get('username');
$password = Input::get('password');

if (!Auth::attempt([ 'email' => $username, 'password' => $password])) {
    # error
    Session::flash('error', 'Invalid Username or Password !');

    return Redirect::to('admin');
}
else {
    # success
    return Redirect::to('admin/dashboard');
}
```

Comment: still “These credentials do not match our records.” when i try to login with new password

Comment: post your login function

Comment: i am using auth laravel for login

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `logic`:

```
if (empty($request->password) && empty($request->retype_password)) {
    $password = $members->password;
  }else{
    $password = bcrypt(Input::get('password'));
  }
```

Comment: `empty('password')` ?? where is that from ??

Comment: i just try to correct the logic, will update, thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think you could use the if condition like this

```
if ($request->input('password') && $request->input('retype_password')) {
        $password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
      }else{
        $password = $members->password;
      }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: no please check the condition you wrote the condition in opposite order.

Comment: `1+2 = 3` and `2+1=3` same. is it ?

Comment: `if (!empty('password') && !empty('retype_password'))`  in this condition you are confirmed that the request has a password to be used for reset and this is where you use the bcrypt function instead you are just using user's old password also you need to change `!empty('password')` to `!empty($request->input('password'))`

Comment: it was there in mine. check it first

Comment: I could see your using bcrypt function to change the user-provided password when the request doesn't have it actually thats why I said you have done is opposite order.

Comment: anyone can help me?